# Eigenstates differ between Qutip and Quspin

Tags: qutip, programming

I am currently trying to adapt a code working well with Qutip to Quspin to optimize it.
I managed to create what I believe are the same systems with both libraries, but I don't get the same eigenstates.
I suspect it is just written differently, or maybe Quspin doesn't understand the Hamiltonian the same way (it might have to do with the "dims"), but still I don't get it.
In the following output, I print $H$ and then the associated ground state with each library:
[image: Qutip vs Quspin for the "same" Hamiltonian]

Here is my code:

```
import qutip as qt
import quspin

N = 3
wx = 1

## Qutip
print("Qutip:\n")

# x Pauli matrix for the particle k
def SX(N,k):
    L=[qt.qeye(2)]*N
    L[k]=qt.sigmax()
    return qt.tensor(L)

# initialization of Hi
Hi=qt.Qobj(np.zeros((2**N,2**N)))
Hi.dims=[[2]*N,[2]*N]

for k1 in range(N):
    Hi=Hi+wx*SX(N,k1)

STi=Hi.eigenstates()[1][0] # recover the ground state vector

print(Hi) # visualize H
print(STi) # visualize the ground state

## Quspin
print("\n\nQuspin:\n")

# basis for H
basis=quspin.basis.spin_basis_1d(N)
print(basis)

# preparing H
x_field=[[wx,i] for i in range(N)]

static = [["x",x_field]]
dynamic = []

H=hamiltonian(static,dynamic,dtype=np.float64,basis=basis)

STi2=H.eigh()[1][0]

print(H.todense()) # visualize sparse matrix H
print(STi2) # visualize the ground state
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Quspin throws the eigenstates a different way than Qutip does.

- Qutip shows each eigenstate such as Hi.eigenstates()[1][0] is the ground, Hi.eigenstates()[1][1] is the first excited state, etc....
- Quspin shows them such as H.eigh()[1][0] are the values the first element of the basis takes for the different states, still with increasing energy, H.eigh()[1][1] is for the second element of the basis, etc...

in order to make it work like Qutip, just do H.eigh()[1].transpose()[0] !